# Prevent user from installing my app if capability not met

Tags: iphone, objective-c, camera, autofocus

I working on an app and its primary need is auto focus camera. How can I prevent users to install this app if they don't have an auto focus camera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well if you really want to prevent users from installing your app if they don't have a autofocus camera then you can add "UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities" key in your info.plist file and can add "auto-focus-camera" value to it. for more info you can visit my blog entry - http://www.makebetterthings.com/blogs/iphone/how-to-prevent-apps-to-being-installed-on-wrong-or-incapable-devices/

Answer (score 1):

You need the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key of your Info.plist (see [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html)); specifically, the capability `auto-focus-camera`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key to your Info.plist file. That key is a dictionary; you need it to contain `auto-focus-camera` set to true.

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<dict>
    <key>auto-focus-camera</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

See the [full list of capabilities](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3) and more details.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key in your Info.plist file. If you include "auto-focus-camera" as one of the items in that array, the app shouldn't install unless the device has that capability.

Have fun!

Comment: Looks like John beat me to it. I should refresh the page before answering a question!  :)