# Preventing Root Users to install my app

Tags: android

I already have a function that closes my app on detection of root device when it start. But now i want to prevent the installation of my app in rooted device for security purposes. Exist an official or unofficial way? I read this: [Prevent user from installing my app if capability not met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296741/prevent-user-from-installing-my-app-if-capability-not-met) but is from 2011 i want to know if there is a solution already. Thanks for yout time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think such a thing is possible currently.

If your app is on the Google Play Store there is one feature which might be able to stop some rooted users which is called [Device Catalog](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7353455). You can specify to exclude uncertified devices or devices which do not pass a SafetyNet check. This does not guarantee the user does not have root, but it could be one way to prevent them from installing it.